# class not printing updated argument in python

Tags: python

I'm a newbie in python so please bear with me. I am trying to define a class named Train, that has the following attributes: `destination, arrival time, speed, and price` then create a **init** that initializes each of these from arguments then create a method named `UpdateSpeed` that takes a speed for an argument and sets the object's speed to the new value. But when I print my new train speed it doesn't print the updated speed but the initialized one. Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, destination, arrivalTime, speed, price):
        self.destination = destination
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.speed = speed
        self.price = price

    def UpdateSpeed(self, speed):
        self.speed = 10
        

myTrain = Train("newyork", 10 , 500, 120)

print(myTrain.speed)
```

Comment: Can you share the code related to your problem?

Comment: just uploaded it, forgot to include it. @BuddyBobIII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the function which changes the speed value.
Also, you don't need to pass speed into the function.

```
class Train:
    def __init__(self, destination, arrivalTime, speed, price):
        self.destination = destination
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.speed = speed
        self.price = price

    def UpdateSpeed(self):
        self.speed = 10
        

myTrain = Train("newyork", 10 , 500, 120)
myTrain.UpdateSpeed()
print(myTrain.speed)
```

**output**

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept answer when possible.